# downloading images from webpage with different links

Tags: wget, curl, images, download

I am trying to download all the images from a webpage.
The images are included as follows:

```
<img src="https://alwaysSamePart.com/SomeRandomLinkThatVaries.jpg">
```

How should I parametrize my `wget` command to specify that I only want the images where the link starts with "https://alwaysSamePart.com/"? because what follows varies every time so I cant just specify a hardcoded link.

Answer (score 1):

```
wget -r -nd -A jpg --accept-regex "https://alwaysSamePart.com/.*.jpg" https://whatever_domain.com
```

- `-r` allows to go recursively through website (you can specify `-l` to limit depth)
- `-nd` prevents directories creation
- `-A` limits download files to jpg images only
- `--accept-regex` limits images to needed pattern only

Comment: didn't work. I tried: wget -E -r -nd -A jpg -P /home/ya/Desktop/myFolder --accept-regex "https://www.someStaticLink/.*.jpg" http://www.whateverDomain.com

There are two issues:
  - I see it only downloads one file in stead of all the images
  - I get the error "removing fileName since it should be rejected"

Comment: @privetDruzia regex is case sensitive. are you sure it's not your case?

Comment: no I think it s not : http://www.scribd.com/doc/98591038/Spacecraft-Attitude-Determination-and-Control-9027709599#scribd

Answer (score 0):

did you try `-A`  or equivalent `--accept` options as given below ?

```
wget "https://alwaysSamePart.com/" -A "*.jpg"
```

Comment: wel the issue is that the images are stored on a website whose URL is totally not the same as the ones where the images are stored.
I.e. the images are stored on www.randomWebsite.com and in the html code of the page you have a url like ""https://alwaysSamePart.com/SomeRandomLinkThatVaries .jpg".

So shouldn't I first try to specify I only want the images from the urls on the webpage. Because imagine some other website stores its images on
"https://alwaysSamePart.com/SomeSLIGHTLYDIFFERENTRandomLinkThatVaries .jpg
"
What would prevent me from downloading all their images too? I'd have gigs...

Comment: tried it: didn't work. error 403

Comment: I have to specify exactly what link. So ideally I'd have to scrape all the urls out of the webpage and then surf to each url individually and then finally save each image.